# yii2 captcha validation not work

Tags: php, yii2, captcha

I'm trying to add captcha to my login page on my `yii2` application.
I have tried some tutorial, the problem is captcha is always correct like no validation.

I have tried this:

- https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-captcha-captcha
- https://mumunotesss.blogspot.com/2015/06/implementation-captcha-on-yii2.html
- http://yii2-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/adding-captcha.html
- [How to add captcha in Yii-2 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865501/how-to-add-captcha-in-yii-2-application)

My code is:

LoginForm

```
public $username;
public $password;
public $rememberMe = true;
private $_user = false;
public $captcha; // add this varible to your model class.

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password','captcha'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            ['captcha', 'captcha','captchaAction'=>'/site/captcha'], // add this code to your rules.
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }
```

SiteController

```
 public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,

            ],
        ];
    }
```

view login.php

```
 <div class="form-goup">
           <?= $form->field($model, 'captcha')->widget(yii\captcha\Captcha::className(), '
['template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3" style="margin-right:25px;">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',
            ]); ?> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I have tryed your code in my project - everything works fine on localhost. Can you check a request url of capcha refreshing and validation rules after render. And can you show the actionLogin of your controller?

Comment: public function actionLogin()
    {
        $this->layout = false;
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        }

        $model->password = '';
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

Comment: @FeR-S have you try input incorrect captcha?

Comment: yes, validation is working fine. Is there are js rules validation after render ? Can do you check?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works but you have syntax errors in it, a letter (this is only cosmetic) and a surplus ' which is completely wrong:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'captcha')->widget(yii\captcha\Captcha::className(), ['template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3" style="margin-right:25px;">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',]); ?> 
</div>
```

This should be in view before <s>submit button</s> `<?php ActiveForm::end();` ?>

Comment: This should be in view before `<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>`

Comment: yes, i put that code before <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

Comment: i mean at the first time, i already put that code before <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

Comment: @NurDiarto Ok, it wasn't specified so it's specified in the answer. Is it working now? Did you replace your code with this code in answer?

Comment: yes i did, i have tryed replace the code, still not working

Comment: @NurDiarto If you changed login() or validate() method in your login form look there for a problem. Also see in debuger what is getting called.

Comment: @Vladimir I had an issue only somewhat similar to this, but the hint in your last comment "If you changed login() or validate() method in your login form look there for a problem." guided me to solving my problem - I moved all my additional login logic out of there and into the SiteController and now my code works. Thank you - also voted your reply up because of this.

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic is old but it might be the issue with your url rules. Have you tried adding:

```
'captcha'=>site/captcha'
```

in your config file, url section